# Implementation Of I2C Slave Using AVR USI Module

Tags: avr, i2c

I've been reading about implementation of I2C (TWI) slave on AVR using USI module.

As the data sheet suggests there exists two application notes on implementing I2C using USI module, here is the one concerning with I2C slave:

[AVR 312 Using The USI Module As I2C Slave](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-2560-Using-the-USI-Module-as-a-I2C-Slave_ApplicationNote_AVR312.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjX9qf_lOz_AhVX0QIHHcc8AnIQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw02JZZ9b-dEPzqCyDr34NDj)

the Application Note Has C Example of impelmenting The USI module as I2C slave and that was the source code i've been reading.
Now here is my question:

I'm Using ATTINY24A and in it's data sheet, on page 130 , Table 14-1 Third Row, it is written that by setting the corresponding bit for SCL and SDA in DDRA Register the "Open Drain" Output Drivers Will be enabled.

> Two-wire mode. Uses SDA (DI) and SCL (USCK) pins(1).
> The Serial Data (SDA) and the Serial Clock (SCL) pins are bi-directional and
> use open-collector output drives. The output drivers are enabled by setting the
> corresponding bit for SDA and SCL in the DDRA register.
> When the output driver is enabled for the SDA pin, the output driver will force
> the line SDA low if the output of the USI Data Register or the corresponding
> bit in the PORTA register is zero. Otherwise, the SDA line will not be driven (i.e.,
> it is released). When the SCL pin output driver is enabled the SCL line will be
> forced low if the corresponding bit in the PORTA register is zero, or by the start
> detector. Otherwise the SCL line will not be driven.
> The SCL line is held low when a start detector detects a start condition and the
> output is enabled. Clearing the Start Condition Flag (USISIF) releases the line.
> The SDA and SCL pin inputs is not affected by enabling this mode. Pull-ups on
> the SDA and SCL port pin are disabled in Two-wire mode.

So In the initialization process of USI as I2C, the DDRA bits for SCL and SDA should be set (=1) and never change during the process of i2c transfers, since the I2C uses Open Drain, and The SCL and SDA is either "HELD LOW" by someone on the bus or "RELEASED" in which the pull up resistors pull the lines Up, right?

But nearly in all implementations of USI Slave **including** the AVR312 C Code Example the DDRA of SDA is set as input (=0) first and it is manipulated during i2c transfer later, why that is? Is this against the data sheet?

I understand that in some point we need to read the value of the SCL and SDA pins, but since it's Open Collector, can't we just read The PIN register without changing the DDRA to input? Or I'm wrong and this is why these implementations change the data direction register DURING i2c transfer?

The Code for USI Initialization in AVR312:

```
void USI_TWI_Slave_Initialise(unsigned char TWI_ownAddress){
Flush_TWI_Buffers();

TWI_slaveAddress = TWI_ownAddress;

PORT_USI |= (1 << PORT_USI_SCL);        // Set SCL high
PORT_USI |= (1 << PORT_USI_SDA);        // Set SDA high
DDR_USI |= (1 << PORT_USI_SCL);         // Set SCL as output
DDR_USI &= ~(1 << PORT_USI_SDA);        // Set SDA as input
USICR = (1 << USISIE) | (0 << USIOIE) | // Enable Start Condition Interrupt. Disable Overflow Interrupt.
        (1 << USIWM1) | (0 << USIWM0) | // Set USI in Two-wire mode. No USI Counter overflow prior
                                        // to first Start Condition (potentail failure)
        (1 << USICS1) | (0 << USICS0) | (0 << USICLK) | // Shift Register Clock Source = External, positive edge
        (0 << USITC);
USISR = 0xF0; // Clear all flags and reset overflow counter}
```

and when slave needs to send ack by pulling the SDA Low:

```
#define SET_USI_TO_SEND_ACK()                                                                                          \
{                                                                                                                  \
    USIDR = 0;                      /* Prepare ACK                         */                                      \
    DDR_USI |= (1 << PORT_USI_SDA); /* Set SDA as output                   */                                      \
    USISR = (0 << USI_START_COND_INT) | (1 << USIOIF) | (1 << USIPF) | (1 << USIDC)                                \
            |                  /* Clear all flags, except Start Cond  */                                           \
            (0x0E << USICNT0); /* set USI counter to shift 1 bit. */                                               \
}
```

Comment: By changing the DDR bit of a port you can emulate an open drain output.